# Track jQuery events bindings using developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, web-developer-toolbar

I have some problems with my JavaScript code, and need to track jQuery event bindings using developer tools (Google Chrome).
Do you know some plugins or tools for this?

P.S. Chrome developers tools event tracking tracks JavaScript events. jQuery events are more difficult

Comment: visual event might help.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference.. just log out the event to the console, maybe even with a nice little function:

```
var log = function(e){

   console.log(e)

}

$('#element).eventListener(log);
```

or inline:

```
$('#element).eventListener(function(e){
   console.log(e);
 });
```

if you want to see the target of the event bubble, use currentTarget - http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/